# How can I redraw a JFrame and its components multiple times per frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, rendering

I am trying to update a JLabel when the user clicks a button, like this pseudocode:

```
private static void ButtonAction()
{
    // Set label to `loading..`

    // Perform action

    // Set label to `ready.`
}
```

I tried to use:

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

No luck so far. Or maybe my button action is too fast to see it switching?

How can I make sure that the user sees both `loading..` and `ready`?

Comment: What type of action are you preforming in between?

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or maybe my button action is too fast to see it switching?

If it is then there is nothing you can do about it unless you want to set a Timer to display the final value.

> How can I make sure that the user sees both loading.. and ready?

The more common case it that when you execute a long running task you need to use `Threads` so you don't prevent the frame from responding to events and repainting itself.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. Maybe you can use a SwingWorker.

If you don't use the SwingWorker, then you will need to create your own Thread and then use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) whenever you want to update the label.